# how to use play store on-demand feature modules with dart code in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play

I have a flutter app that contains large dart files, I don't want these files to be downloaded at the install-time of the app but later, is it possible to achieve this in Flutter using play store on-demand feature modules?